# How to profile Swift framework?

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, profiling

I know how to profile iOS application, but I never profiled framework. How it is done? I can't find any information on how it is done.

I want to improve performance of some algorithms. I'm afraid I will make wrong choices, because I have no experience with it.

For example, I can add a target and profile it, but I never see a project on github that has a target for this purpose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily. Run test target. Open debug navigator (or ⌘6). Select CPU. Open "Profile in instruments". This can crash Xcode, however, Instruments would be working. Also notice "Invert Call Tree" option on the left.